# How to Import Cash Refunds Via CSV Import

Tags: file, csv, import, upload, netsuite

I created custom fields that need to be populated via a CSV import for Cash Refunds. Is it possible to update a Cash Refund Record via a CSV import?

If so, what is the record type you choose when using the import assistant? There is no Cash Refund option. I've tried credit memo and sales order. Neither worked for updating a cash refund. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CSV import is not supported for Cash Refunds.  See [SuiteAnswer 10008](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10008) for a list of supported record types.